# Скрипт записи данных в поле таблицы

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Существует таблица `Users` и таблица `Balance`. Связанные связью `@OneToMany`: один пользователь - много балансов.

Пример структуры в ответе метода
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно? Написать скрипт-логику по следующему алгоритму:

1. Метод получает список пользователей из БД из таблицы `Users`
2. Пробегаемся по списку и получаем балансы пользователей `Balance`
3. Находим записи у которых поле `tax = null`
4. Записываем для таких записей поле `tax = 0.20`
5. Значения где `tax != null` пропускаем
6. Завершение

Часть логики которую написал но не могу закончить. Как сделать проверку по полю `tax` и записать данные для записей `tax = null` корректно? Достаточно будет примера.

```
public class JobUserBalance {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final UserRepo userRepo;
    private final BalanceRepo balanceRepo;
    private final BalanceService balanceService;

    public JobUserBalance(UserService userService, UserRepo userRepo, BalanceRepo balanceRepo, BalanceService balanceService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
        this.balanceRepo = balanceRepo;
        this.balanceService = balanceService;
    }

    public void setTax() {
        Iterable<Users> users = userRepo.findAll(); // получаем список пользователей
        users.forEach(users1 -> users1.getBalance().forEach(balance -> balance.getTax())); // пробегаемся по сущности Users получаем балансы, далее поле tax
        // если значение tax у пользователя = null, то для каждой записи где null для каждого пользователя проставляем значение 0.20
        // записи где tax != null пропускаем


    }
}
```

таблица User

```
package com.example.rabbit_new2.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "users_balance")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "code")
    private Integer code;

    @Column(insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime dateCreated;
    private LocalDateTime dateModified;



    @PrePersist
    void onCreate() {
        this.setDateCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
        this.setDateModified(LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    @PreUpdate
    void onUpdate() {
        this.setDateModified(LocalDateTime.now());
    }


    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "balance_calc",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    )
    private List<Balance> balance;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinTable(
            name = "data_users",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    )
    private DataUser dataUser;


}
```

таблица Balance

```
package com.example.rabbit_new2.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "balance_calc")
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Balance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "sum")
    private Double sum;

    @Column(name = "tax")
    private Double tax;

    @Column(name = "result")
    private Double result;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;


    @Column(insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime dateCreated;
    private LocalDateTime dateModified;



    @PrePersist
    void onCreate() {
        this.setDateCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
        this.setDateModified(LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    @PreUpdate
    void onUpdate() {
        this.setDateModified(LocalDateTime.now());
    }


}
```

Comment: А в чём сложность возникла? У вас же всё готово уже. Вы просто проходитесь по списку балансов каждого пользователя, и если поле `tax` очередного баланса равно `null`, устанавливаете его в 0.2.

Comment: Сложности возникли с написанием проверки после получения списка пользователей и балансов. Пока еще не хватает уровня знаний, ранее с сущностями не работал. Если не затруднит добавить пример, то очень поможете.

Comment: Приведите ваши классы-сущности `User` и `Balance`

Comment: Добавил выше в описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, вот:

```
for (User user : users) { // проход по списку пользователей
    for (Balance balance : user.getBalances()) { // проход по списку балансов очередного пользователя
        if (balance.getTax() == null) { // если поле tax очередного баланса содержит значение null
            balance.setTax(0.2); // устанавливаем его в 0.2
            balanceService.save(balance); // сохраняем результат, чтобы он был записан в БД
        }
    }
}
```

Если делать при помощи `forEach()`, как вы пытались, то может получиться так:

```
users.forEach(user -> user.getBalance().forEach(balance -> {
    if (balance.getTax() == null) {
        balance.setTax(0.2);
        balanceService.save(balance);
    }
}));
```

Скорее всего, код можно ещё как-нибудь улучшить и сократить.

---

Помимо этого, хочу обратить внимание на странность в приведённом вами классе. Вы внедряете в него и репозитории, и соответствующие им сервисы. Так быть не должно. В идеале репозиторий внедряется только в одноимённый с ним сервис, а вся дальнейшая работа с сущностями в приложении осуществляется через сервисы.

Соответственно, вам должно быть достаточно внедрения `userService` и `balanceService`. Все действия, которые вы планируете делать над сущностями, должны быть покрыты этими сервисами.

И это уже не говоря о том, что решению всей этой задачи и вовсе не нужно находиться в отдельном классе. Это вполне себе работа какого-нибудь из двух упомянутых выше сервисов. Скорее даже `userService`-а.

Задача представляет собой смену null-поля `tax` балансов пользователей. Значит, вполне логично в сервисе юзеров создать метод `changeNullTaxBalances()`, в который и поместить приведённый в начале ответа код.

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ. Обязательно приму во внимание.